# How to combining two search parameters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, search

I am just getting into Rails and want to preform a simple search FROM destination TO destination. I have the basic search functionality working and connected to the database but when I choose FROM and TWO the output is combined and I get all transports FROM the specific text and all transports TO the specific text. I want to filter them and only have the ones that go FROM TO.

Here is what I have so far.

```
class Transport < ApplicationRecord
def self.searchfrom(searchfrom)
  where("strtloc LIKE ?", "%#{searchfrom}%") 
end

def self.searchto(searchto)
  where("endloc LIKE ?", "%#{searchto}%") 
end
end
```

I basically want to add AND in between the two parameters but I am stuck.

This is my transports_controller.rb

```
if params[:searchfrom]
  @transports = Transport.searchfrom(params[:searchfrom])
else
  @transports = Transport.all
end

if params[:searchto]
  @transports = Transport.searchto(params[:searchto])
else
  @transports = Transport.all
end
```

I also want the ability to only select FROM. So I cant really do a simple AND statement. But one at a time.

Any help apreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please check this answer:

[Ruby on Rails: Search Form - multiple search fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577937/ruby-on-rails-search-form-multiple-search-fields#11613857)

You should find this is related to you problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do either of the following:

`@transports = Transport.where("strtloc LIKE ? AND endloc LIKE ?", "#{params[:searchfrom]}%", "#{params[:searchto]}%")`

It'll do an AND operations between the two parameters.

**or**

```
@transports = Transport.where("strtloc LIKE ?", "#{params[:searchfrom]}%")
# first search for start locations
@transports = @transports.where("endloc LIKE ?", "#{params[:searchto]}%")
# then search for end locations in the result of start location.
```

Also check: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609005/ruby-on-rails-advanced-search/11610450#11610450)

Comment: I tried the first approach sadly it does not work. I am probably missing something in my transports_controller. 

EDIT! It works, I modified something in my controller before, I reverted to what I posted here at fist and now it works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: @Robert, Pleased to hear that.